# Pulling Git from server

Tags: git, ssh, github, ssh-keys

I've managed to commit my changes locally to Github.  Now I want to update it on my server.  How do I connect to my server to pull the files from Github?

Answer (score 4):

If the repository doesn't exist yet:

```
git clone git@github.com:sam_mitchell/my-project.git
```

If the repository exists, but you don't have a remote set up:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:sam_mitchell/my-project.git
git pull origin master
```

If you already have your remotes set up, then:

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a new ssh-key on the server. **Do not share keys across machines!**

Add the public key to github.

Clone.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your server; have you tried `ssh`ing into it, making sure that Git is installed and then cloning it as normal.

You'll need to set up the ssh keys on the server and add them to your GitHub account if you want to be able to have read+write access to your repositories.